# Bundle install failure for an existing ruby app. I suspect libv8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git, installation

I have the rather unfortunate position of inheriting a rails app from a previous developer. I have the joy of both trying to learn ruby and picking apart the old code to fix what's broken.  I don't have any means for contacting the former developer, nor do I have much knowledge of the app other than that it uses ruby on rails. I'm much more familiar with the .net environment, so getting RoR up and running is proving to be a bit of a challenge.

I'm simply trying to clone their code repo locally and try to run their code on a local rails server. I was able to clone, the next thing I tried was to run bundle install and I got this massive block of text that I can't make heads or tails of.

**Massive wall of text below**

```
Justin@JVB-MBP /c/Sites/mymouthworks (master)
$ bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 10.1.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using minitest 4.7.5
Using multi_json 1.8.4
Using atomic 1.1.14
Using thread_safe 0.1.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.38
Using activesupport 4.0.2
Using builder 3.1.4
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using actionpack 4.0.2
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 4.0.2
Using activemodel 4.0.2
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.3
Using arel 4.0.2
Using activerecord 4.0.2
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.1.2
Using sass 3.2.14
Using bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1
Using will_paginate 3.0.4
Using bootstrap-will_paginate 0.0.9
Using bundler 1.7.7
Using chunky_png 1.3.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using thor 0.18.1
Using railties 4.0.2
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using commonjs 0.2.7
Using fssm 0.2.10
Using compass 0.12.3
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using compass-rails 1.1.7
Using date_validator 0.7.0
Using jbuilder 1.5.3
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using json 1.8.1
Using less 2.4.0
Using less-rails 2.4.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150212-3448-1yjlu6v.
rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8 3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:58:in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, but it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:42:in `block in build_libv8!'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `chdir'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `build_libv8!'
    from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
    from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/libv8-3.16.14.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.

Justin@JVB-MBP /c/Sites/mymouthworks (master)
$
```

To me, it looks like there's an issue with libv8, but there is also a warning about python 2 not being installed, which it is, along with being added to the path variable. I should add my dev environment is 64-bit Windows 8.1. Has anyone got this working?

Thank you.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, could you please explain why this question is not good? I really don't know the first thing about ruby so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that libv8 did not successfully install.

Bundler will not continue until that step succeeds. You need to run:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'
```

A nice feature about Bundler is that it gives you the command you need to run in order to proceed. If this command fails you should get a better error message to work with.

Comment: Yes. This worked. But I had to specify that I needed to use V8.  Thank you. Now it's complaining about needing mysql2. Any advice on that bit?

Comment: When errors occur during 'bundle install', the solution tends to follow a standard pattern: run the command Bundler gives you; if you hit a new error, try to work through it or search online; get the command to succeed; run 'bundle install'. Repeat until all gems are installed. This is very common. FWIW anything Ruby is going to be harder on Windows-- I highly recommend switching to a Unix-based system while still early in the process.

Comment: Ugh. What a pain. It's just not fun because I'm open to using a Mac but a lot of my colleagues are deeply rooted in windows so I've got to sort of go with the flow, even if it's not ideal for this language. Thanks for your advice.